# How to break down a given text into words from the dictionary?

Tags: string, algorithm, language-agnostic, data-structures

This is an interview question. Suppose you have a string `text` and a `dictionary` (a set of strings). How do you break down `text` into substrings such that each substring is found in the `dictionary`.

For example you can break down `"thisisatext"` into `["this", "is", "a", "text"]` using `/usr/share/dict/words`.

I believe backtracking can solve this problem (in pseudo-Java):

```
void solve(String s, Set<String> dict, List<String> solution) {
   if (s.length == 0)
      return
   for each prefix of s found in dict
      solve(s without prefix, dict, solution + prefix)
}

List<String> solution = new List<String>()
solve(text, dict, solution)
```

Does it make sense? Would you optimize the step of searching the prefixes in the dictionary? What data structures would you recommend?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but your solution is non polynomial. It is possible to solve this in at most O(n^2) using trie and DP (It is actually O(k) where k is the length of the longest word in the dictionary) . Let me know if you need the answer.

Comment: @ElKamina Thanks. I would like to hear the DP solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution assumes the existence of Trie data structure for the dictionary. Further, for each node in Trie, assumes the following functions:

1. node.IsWord() : Returns true if the path to that node is a word
2. node.IsChild(char x): Returns true if there exists a child with label x
3. node.GetChild(char x): Returns the child node with label x

> ```
> Function annotate( String str, int start, int end, int root[], TrieNode node):
> i = start
> while i<=end:
>     if node.IsChild ( str[i]):
>         node = node.GetChild( str[i] )
>         if node.IsWord():
>             root[i+1] = start
>         i+=1
>     else:
>         break;
>
> end = len(str)-1
> root = [-1 for i in range(len(str)+1)]
> for start= 0:end:
>     if start = 0 or root[start]>=0:
>         annotate(str, start, end, root, trieRoot)
>
> index  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11
> str:   t  h  i  s  i  s  a  t  e  x  t
> root: -1 -1 -1 -1  0 -1  4  6 -1  6 -1   7
> ```

I will leave the part for you to list the words that make up the string by reverse traversing the root.

Time complexity is O(nk) where n is the length of the string and k is the length of the longest word in the dictionary.

PS: I am assuming following words in the dictionary: this, is, a, text, ate.

Comment: Doesn't root need to be an array of lists? Otherwise you'll lose multiple paths through the string that converge at the same place

Comment: @TimothyJones I thought the poster wanted one solution, not all solutions. You are right, by having a list you get to print all the word combinations that form the string.

Comment: It might also be worth adding the time complexity to your answer - I think it's O(n.k), where n is the size of the text, and k is the longest word in the dictionary. (plus whatever it takes to read the final path - in the non-multiple path version I think it's O(m), where m is the number of words in the result).

Comment: Can you please tell me what this step done is 
     root = [-1 for i in range(len(str)+1)].

Comment: @jhamb That is just initializing an array with -1s. Eg. If string length is 3, root = [-1, -1, -1]

Comment: ElKamina , Can you please suggest me some link, about suffix array, suffix tree. I found a lot, but I didn't find any good tutorial.

Comment: @jhamb Have you checked wikipedia pages? Also check the links at the bottom of those pages.

Comment: 1. Remove this line: `if start = 0 or root[start]>=0:` if `str` contains undefined words.  2. Do `root[i+1] = start` only when `root[i+1] == -1` to return the longest matches.

Comment: <<I thought the poster wanted one solution, not all solutions. >> My understanding of the poster's question: break down string into substrings which will cover the *entire* original string (no leftover letters). Example: beerevery -- in that case, it is a problem that your solution could first have a value for root[9] = 4, then later overwrite root[9] = 5; beer | every is a correct split; but beere | very is an incorrect split; I think your above algorithm will fail in its current state (i.e. unable to reconstruct a full, correct split of the string)...

Answer (score 5):

There is a very thorough writeup for the solution to this problem in this [blog post.](http://thenoisychannel.com/2011/08/08/retiring-a-great-interview-problem/)

The basic idea is just to memoize the function you've written and you'll have an O(n^2) time, O(n) space algorithm.

Comment: +1 Nice answer with additional commentary on several approaches and how a variety of candidates respond.  As the blogger states, if someone can't do a competent job on this toy problem, they'd have a very hard time in large scale information retrieval and NLP.

Answer (score 4):

**Approach 1-**
[Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) looks to be a close fit here. Generate trie of the words in english dictionary. This trie building is one time cost. After trie is built then your `string` can be easily compared letter by letter. if at any point you encounter a leaf in the trie you can assume you found a word, add this to a list & move on with your traversal. Do the traversal till you have reached the end of your `string`. The list is output.

Time Complexity for search - O(word_length).

Space Complexity - O(charsize * word_length * no_words). Size of your dictionary.

**Approach 2 -** I have heard of [Suffix Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree), never used them but it might be useful here.

**Approach 3 -** is more pedantic & a lousy alternative. you have already suggested this.

You could try the other way around. Run through the `dict` is check for sub-string match. Here I am assuming the keys in `dict` are the `words` of the english dictionary `/usr/share/dict/words`. So psuedo code looks something like this -

```
(list) splitIntoWords(String str, dict d)
{
    words = []
    for (word in d)
    {
        if word in str
            words.append(word);
    }
    return words;
}
```

Complexity - O(n) running through entire dict + O(1) for substring match.

Space - worst case O(n) if `len(words) == len(dict)`

As others have pointed out, this does require backtracking.

Comment: You still have to deal with backtracking, right?  If your dictionary contains both "the" and "these", then the inputs "thesebugs" and "thesets" will cause problems.

Comment: This seems to only find those words that occur in the string. There is an additional condition in the problem - the words must cover the whole string without overlapping.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem using [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) and [Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashing).

Calculate the hash of every word in the dictionary. Use the hash function you like the most. I would use something like (a1 * B ^ (n - 1) + a2 * B ^ (n - 2) + ... + an * B ^ 0) % P, where a1a2...an is a string, n is the length of the string, B is the base of the polynomial and P is a large prime number. If you have the hash value of a string a1a2...an you can calculate the hash value of the string a1a2...ana(n+1) in constant time: (hashValue(a1a2...an) * B + a(n+1)) % P.

The complexity of this part is O(N * M), where N is the number of words in the dictionary and M is the length of the longest word in the dictionary.

Then, use a DP function like this:

```
   bool vis[LENGHT_OF_STRING];
   bool go(char str[], int length, int position)
   {
      int i;

      // You found a set of words that can solve your task.
      if (position == length) {
          return true;
      }

      // You already have visited this position. You haven't had luck before, and obviously you won't have luck this time.
      if (vis[position]) {
         return false;
      }
      // Mark this position as visited.
      vis[position] = true;

      // A possible improvement is to stop this loop when the length of substring(position, i) is greater than the length of the longest word in the dictionary.
      for (i = position; position < length; i++) {
         // Calculate the hash value of the substring str(position, i);
         if (hashValue is in dict) {
            // You can partition the substring str(i + 1, length) in a set of words in the dictionary.
            if (go(i + 1)) {
               // Use the corresponding word for hashValue in the given position and return true because you found a partition for the substring str(position, length).
               return true;
            }
         }
      }

      return false;
   }
```

The complexity of this algorithm is O(N * M), where N is the length of the string and M is the length of the longest word in the dictionary or O(N ^ 2), depending if you coded the improvement or not.

So the total complexity of the algorithm will be: O(N1 * M) + O(N2 * M) (or O(N2 ^ 2)), where N1 is the number of words in the dictionary, M is the length of the longest word in the dictionary and N2 is the lenght of the string).

If you can't think of a nice hash function (where there are not any collision), other possible solution is to use Tries or a Patricia trie (if the size of the normal trie is very large) (I couldn't post links for these topics because my reputation is not high enough to post more than 2 links). But in you use this, the complexity of your algorithm will be O(N * M) * O(Time needed to find a word in the trie), where N is the length of the string and M is the length of the longest word in the dictionary.

I hope it helps, and I apologize for my poor english.