# Word Break time complexity

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, dictionary, time-complexity

I came across the word break problem which goes something like this:

> Given an input string and a dictionary of words,segment the input
>   string into a space-separated sequence of dictionary words if
>   possible.

For example, if the input string is "applepie" and dictionary contains a standard set of English words,then we would return the string "apple pie" as output

Now I myself came up with a quadratic time solution. And I came across various [other quadratic time solutions using DP](http://thenoisychannel.com/2011/08/08/retiring-a-great-interview-problem/).

However in Quora a user posted a [linear time solution to this problem](http://www.quora.com/Programming-Interviews/Write-a-program-that-breaks-up-a-string-of-words-with-no-spaces-into-a-string-with-appropriate-spaces-eg-i-p-peanutbutter-o-p-peanut-butter/answer/Gaurav-Mishra-29)

I cant figure out how it comes out to be linear. Is their some mistake in the time complexity calculations? What is the best possible **worst case time complexity** for this problem. I am posting the most common DP solution here

```
String SegmentString(String input, Set<String> dict) {
    int len = input.length();
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        String prefix = input.substring(0, i);
        if (dict.contains(prefix)) {
              String suffix = input.substring(i, len);
              if (dict.contains(suffix)) {
                  return prefix + " " + suffix;
              }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: How ambiguity should be resolved? `expertsexchange => [expert, sex, change], [experts, exchange]`

Comment: The linear time solution works only in the case of two words. What is your requirement on that? The simplest general solution involves generating a power set of 2^n items, DP can make it faster to O(n^2).

Comment: apparently another linear timed algo can be found on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793387/how-to-break-down-a-given-text-into-words-from-the-dictionary?rq=1 look at the second answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'linear' time algorithm that you [linked here](http://www.quora.com/Programming-Interviews/Write-a-program-that-breaks-up-a-string-of-words-with-no-spaces-into-a-string-with-appropriate-spaces-eg-i-p-peanutbutter-o-p-peanut-butter/answer/Gaurav-Mishra-29) works as follows:

If the string is `sharperneedle` and dictionary is `sharp, sharper, needle`,

1. It pushes `sharp` in the string.
2. Then it sees that `er` is not in dictionary, but if we combine it with the last word added, then `sharper` exists. Hence it pops out the last element and pushes this in.

IMO the above logic fails for string `eaterror` and dictionary `eat, eater, error`.

Here `er` shall pop out eat from the list, and push in `eater`. The remaining string `ror` shall not be recognized and discarded.

As regards the code you posted, as mentioned in the comments, this works for only two words with one partition place.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa The description of the algorithm is as per the link http://www.quora.com/Programming-Interviews/Write-a-program-that-breaks-up-a-string-of-words-with-no-spaces-into-a-string-with-appropriate-spaces-eg-i-p-peanutbutter-o-p-peanut-butter/answer/Gaurav-Mishra-29 given by OP and not the code posted.